# can template alias be used for partial specialization?

Tags: c++, c++11, partial-specialization

Given a template alias

```
template<unsigned U>
using uint_ = integral_constant<unsigned,U>;
```

The partial specialization of

```
template<class T,class P>
struct size{};
```

as

```
template <class T,unsigned U>
struct size<T,uint_<U>>{};
```

generates a warning as`template parameter can not be deduced` for clang 3.1 while no warning is generated with gcc 4.7

So, is it malformed code?

Comment: I see no reason why that should not work. Alias templates are substituted immediately.

Comment: Not only it gives warning in clang 3.1 but it ignores the specialization if I try to instantiate it.  However using integral_constant directly in place of alias works as usual. I guess it is clang bug.

Comment: @abir: That means template alias isn't implemented correctly in Clang.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code is perfectly fine in C++11. The Clang's warning can be ignored.

Answer (score 3):

Another guy said that this is a Clang bug. You can work it around if you change the using declaration like this

```
template<unsigned T, unsigned U = T>
using uint_ = integral_constant<unsigned,U>;
```

As an educated guess, apparently Clang does not correctly update the identity of the template parameter that appears in the type-id. So it thinks in your example that the resulting type `uint_<U>` refers to the first parameter of the partial specialization (because within `uint_` that is the case, but not in the point of use). Alternatively you can exchange the order at the point of use

```
template <unsigned U,class T>
struct size<T,uint_<U>>{};
```